# Duplicate Image in VirtualStringTree Delphi

Tags: delphi, tvirtualstringtree

I use a TVirtualStringTree component. With this code the image will show duplicated. How can I fix it?

[image: duplicate icon]

```
    procedure TFAbzarCode.VST1GetImageIndex(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
      Node: PVirtualNode; Kind: TVTImageKind; Column: TColumnIndex;
      var Ghosted: Boolean; var ImageIndex: TImageIndex);
    var
      NodeData: ^rTreeData;
      MImageIndex:integer;
    begin
      NodeData := Sender.GetNodeData(Node); 
      ImageIndex:=NodeData.ImageIndex;
    end;
```

I want only one icon beside the text

Comment: Please provide a [mre], (with emphasis on **minimal**, that still produce the problem, including also a data structure). The code you show doesn't paint anything, it only gets the image index.

Comment: Check the `Kind` parameter

Comment: Ondrej kelle how use kind parameter?

Answer (score 1):

This code fixed the problem.

```
procedure TvTreeControl.vTreeGetImageIndex(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode; Kind: TVTImageKind; Column: TColumnIndex; var Ghosted: Boolean; var ImageIndex: Integer);
    var pNode  : PNodeRec;
    begin
         ImageIndex := -1;
         if Assigned(Node) then
              begin
              pNode  := Sender.GetNodeData( Node);
              if pNode.NodeData <> NIL then
                   begin
                   if Kind <> TVTImageKind(2)then
                        ImageIndex := pNode.NodeData.ImageIndex;
                   end;
              end;
    end;
```

Comment: Doesn't `TVTImageKind(2)` have a name?

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?